# Declaring curried function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, currying

Given interface for curried function with one parameter

```
interface CurriedFunction1<T1, R> {
   (): CurriedFunction1<T1, R>
   (t1: T1): R
}
```

How can I declare generic function of that type?

The following declartions don't work:

```
declare let myFunction: CurriedFunction1<T[], string> // Cannot find name 'T'.
declare let myFunction2:<T>CurriedFunction1<T[], string> // '( expected.
```

Comment: "declare generic function" --- shouldn't your values be of particular types? You should instantiate a generic type with particular type. eg `declare let myFunction: CurriedFunction1<string[], string>`

Comment: Well, this works: `declare function a<T>(): T;` `declare const b: <T>() => T;`. So I can declare functions using generic function declaration, but if I can't define functions using generic interface with `(..)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your comment, I now understand what you're trying to do!  It's not possible.  The list of type parameters of the call signature is fixed when the call signature is declared in the interface, and there is no support for adding universal quantification of type variables to an existing type such as `CurriedFunction1<T[], string>`.  The closest you could come would be to introduce a wrapper function that has to be called with a type argument to get the actual `CurriedFunction1`:

```
declare let myFunction: <T>() => CurriedFunction1<T[], string>
```